# Make the div scrollable based on the content

Tags: html, css

The requirement is to make the div with class ".container" scrollable. The other divs should render as per the specified height. At present this content creates a scroll at body level.
Also flex display related answer is preferred over display as grid ones.

```css
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row header" style="height:200px">
      <div>header</div>
      <span>sized to content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
      <div>
        <span style="height:50px">content</span> (fills remaining space)
        <div class="container">
          <div style="width:100%;height:700px;background-color:green"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Update: The snippet is updated to elaborate that height or overflow set to the container does not work right. Tried it in my laptop with 1920 x 1080 resolution in chrome, there are two scrolls, one from the outer body too. Need just a single scroll on the container which would work as responsive for multiple resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments I found in answers, I suggested this solution using CSS `calc()` function:

```css
:root {
   /* set the height of other elements here */
    --fixHeight: 250px;
}


.box .row {
    border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.container {
    height: calc(100vh - var(--fixHeight));
    background-color: green
}

.container>div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 3px red;
    /* maybe overflow-y: auto; also works */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="row header" style="height:200px">
        <div>header</div>
        <span>sized to content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
        <div>
            <span style="height:50px">content</span> (fills remaining space)
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    some div contents
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur delectus deleniti, dignissimos distinctio ducimus ea est facilis illo inventore iste laudantium nemo nostrum optio quaerat quos, repellat repellendus temporibus totam ullam unde ut veniam vitae. Aut consequuntur dolore, enim excepturi minus, nisi quisquam ratione sit suscipit ullam velit, vitae voluptates. A alias amet, asperiores delectus eius eos est ex, facere in ipsam laudantium nostrum optio possimus quas quo quos repellendus sunt, suscipit voluptate voluptatibus. Ad aliquam, consequatur consequuntur delectus, dolores ducimus eligendi eum facilis iste libero mollitia natus officiis optio pariatur quaerat repellendus repudiandae, sunt vel. Aliquam aperiam at, atque blanditiis consectetur culpa deleniti dignissimos dolorem, doloremque dolorum ducimus ea earum esse eum excepturi facere inventore ipsam ipsum, iure labore libero nam neque nesciunt nobis numquam omnis possimus provident quam ratione reiciendis sapiente similique sit soluta suscipit tempora vel voluptates! Adipisci, alias aliquid architecto consequatur cupiditate dignissimos doloremque, et facere illo ipsa nam, neque nostrum officiis placeat provident quidem quis repellat sapiente sint voluptas! Architecto aspernatur consectetur culpa cumque cupiditate dicta, dignissimos dolor doloremque ducimus error expedita fugiat fugit inventore itaque laboriosam molestias odio omnis optio repudiandae sequi sunt suscipit vel, velit veritatis voluptatibus? Commodi consequuntur debitis ex, modi nemo nihil nostrum sequi! Animi dolores eos error esse facilis nam nemo saepe sequi suscipit veritatis! Accusamus alias aperiam at cumque, debitis dignissimos hic libero magni maxime mollitia natus ratione sequi velit veniam vero! Ab animi asperiores beatae cupiditate dignissimos dolores ea eius eum hic id impedit inventore, libero magnam maxime minima molestias nam nemo nobis nulla placeat quae reprehenderit temporibus voluptatem! At autem commodi consectetur corporis, delectus dolore earum fuga molestiae nobis, omnis placeat, qui totam ullam. A adipisci aliquid aperiam beatae corporis cupiditate deleniti dignissimos dolorem dolorum fuga fugiat id in itaque maiores modi necessitatibus neque nobis odio omnis optio pariatur perferendis perspiciatis praesentium quaerat qui, quia quo recusandae rem repellendus repudiandae temporibus ullam unde voluptatibus. Dignissimos dolorum ducimus eaque eum? Accusantium corporis ducimus ex hic, molestias neque nulla optio rerum sapiente. Assumenda consectetur consequuntur ducimus expedita, harum, ipsum iusto minima necessitatibus nesciunt numquam officia perferendis quasi rerum, vel vero! Aliquam cum eligendi enim error explicabo harum numquam quas quis saepe sapiente similique unde ut velit voluptate, voluptates? Accusamus asperiores cum delectus deleniti dignissimos dolor enim, explicabo facere facilis illum ipsam laudantium magnam magni maiores molestiae necessitatibus neque numquam obcaecati odio officiis omnis optio praesentium quas quidem quo recusandae, reiciendis repellat, reprehenderit rerum sequi totam ullam vel voluptates. Accusamus commodi cupiditate deleniti eius fugiat fugit natus sequi temporibus, voluptatibus? A accusamus ad alias atque blanditiis commodi consequatur cum debitis deserunt enim exercitationem, expedita hic ipsam, libero minima minus molestiae mollitia possimus quis quos saepe, sunt vel velit voluptates voluptatibus!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also if you want to be more dynamic (means that the height of other elements are calculated automatically) you can set a class called `wrapper` to every other element you want to calculate its height and then use the JavaScript code like below:

```js
let allOthers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
let containerElem = document.querySelector(".container");

let allHeights = 0;

allOthers.forEach(function (element, index) {
    let elemHeight = getComputedStyle(element).height;
    allHeights += parseFloat( elemHeight );
});

console.log(allHeights);

let containerHeight = "calc(100vh - " + allHeights + "px)";

containerElem.style.height = containerHeight;
```

```css
.header {
    height: 250px;
}


.box .row {
    border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.container {
    background-color: green
}

.container>div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 3px red;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="row header wrapper">
        <div>header</div>
        <span>sized to content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
        <div>
            <span style="height:50px" class="wrapper">content</span> (fills remaining space)
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    some div contents
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur delectus deleniti, dignissimos distinctio ducimus ea est facilis illo inventore iste laudantium nemo nostrum optio quaerat quos, repellat repellendus temporibus totam ullam unde ut veniam vitae. Aut consequuntur dolore, enim excepturi minus, nisi quisquam ratione sit suscipit ullam velit, vitae voluptates. A alias amet, asperiores delectus eius eos est ex, facere in ipsam laudantium nostrum optio possimus quas quo quos repellendus sunt, suscipit voluptate voluptatibus. Ad aliquam, consequatur consequuntur delectus, dolores ducimus eligendi eum facilis iste libero mollitia natus officiis optio pariatur quaerat repellendus repudiandae, sunt vel. Aliquam aperiam at, atque blanditiis consectetur culpa deleniti dignissimos dolorem, doloremque dolorum ducimus ea earum esse eum excepturi facere inventore ipsam ipsum, iure labore libero nam neque nesciunt nobis numquam omnis possimus provident quam ratione reiciendis sapiente similique sit soluta suscipit tempora vel voluptates! Adipisci, alias aliquid architecto consequatur cupiditate dignissimos doloremque, et facere illo ipsa nam, neque nostrum officiis placeat provident quidem quis repellat sapiente sint voluptas! Architecto aspernatur consectetur culpa cumque cupiditate dicta, dignissimos dolor doloremque ducimus error expedita fugiat fugit inventore itaque laboriosam molestias odio omnis optio repudiandae sequi sunt suscipit vel, velit veritatis voluptatibus? Commodi consequuntur debitis ex, modi nemo nihil nostrum sequi! Animi dolores eos error esse facilis nam nemo saepe sequi suscipit veritatis! Accusamus alias aperiam at cumque, debitis dignissimos hic libero magni maxime mollitia natus ratione sequi velit veniam vero! Ab animi asperiores beatae cupiditate dignissimos dolores ea eius eum hic id impedit inventore, libero magnam maxime minima molestias nam nemo nobis nulla placeat quae reprehenderit temporibus voluptatem! At autem commodi consectetur corporis, delectus dolore earum fuga molestiae nobis, omnis placeat, qui totam ullam. A adipisci aliquid aperiam beatae corporis cupiditate deleniti dignissimos dolorem dolorum fuga fugiat id in itaque maiores modi necessitatibus neque nobis odio omnis optio pariatur perferendis perspiciatis praesentium quaerat qui, quia quo recusandae rem repellendus repudiandae temporibus ullam unde voluptatibus. Dignissimos dolorum ducimus eaque eum? Accusantium corporis ducimus ex hic,
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest an element with `height: 100%;` into an element with a fixed or restricted height. Then you can set `overflow-y: scroll;` on the element with the height: 100%; which will contain all of your content.

I added some content to demonstrate the behavior.

```css
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.container {
  height: 78.5vh;
  max-width: 100;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 10px red;
}

.header {
  height: 20vh;
}

.content {
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.container>div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body,
.box {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row header">
      <div>header</div>
      <span>sized to content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="container">
        <div><span>content</span> (fills remaining space)<br>NOW<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>WE<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CAN<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>SCROLL<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is a outer scroll which is not needed.

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar I think the answer of @カメロン is correct. But when you have a ```.container``` with the ```height: 700px;``` and also another ```.header``` div with ```height: 200px;```, that makes the body to have vertical scroll. If you do not want that, change the ```.container``` height to for example ```80px```.

Comment: @hamid Cant it be dynamic, I mean the container has to take up the rest of the space below available and work for different screens with varying heights

Comment: @hamid-davodi it does not work, kindly check the above comment

Comment: @DineshKumar "The requirement is to make the div with class ".container" scrollable. The other divs should render as per the specified height." - The requested container is scrollable and the other divs are rendering at their non-specified *auto* height because there are no heights associated. I can't read your mind on what you're wanting so if there are other requirements beyond the ones I met you'll have to make those clear to me.

Comment: @DineshKumar So if I am understanding you now, you want the body height and the elements inside to not have any scroll and to fit into 100 viewport height? So you basically just want the scroll off the body?

Comment: @DineshKumar You can check my updated answer. If this isn't want you want you're going to have to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set height to your parent container. Px or any property. Then set overflow auto

Comment: I have updated the question, still issue exists.